# How to show 2 timer in a single page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to show 2 buttons for timer of 3 minutes, but the problem is that my second timer works perfectly but first timer doesn't, even if I remove the second timer still there is some problem with the first timer. Code is same for both the timer just variables are different

```
<table>
<tr class="odd">
           <td></td>
            <th scope="row"><div class="timer">
            <time id="countdown"></time>
            </div>
            </th>
            <td></td>
            <td><form name="form"><input type="button" name="start" id="colourButton" value="Start Time!" onclick="showDiv()"/></form></td>
          </tr>
<tr class="odd">
           <td></td>
            <th scope="row"><div class="timer">
            <time id="countdown2"></time>
            </div>
            </th>
            <td></td>
            <td><form name="form1"><input type="button" name="start1" id="colourButton2" value="Start Time!" onclick="showDiv2()"/></form></td>
          </tr>
</table>


<script>
function showDiv() {
    document.form.colourButton.disabled = true;
   var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
}
 var seconds = 180;
      function secondPassed() {
          var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60),
              remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

          if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
              remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
          }

          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
          if (seconds == 0) {
              clearInterval(countdownTimer);
             //form1 is your form name
            window.alert("Times Up");
          } else {
              seconds--;
          }
      }


       function showDiv2() {
    document.form1.colourButton2.disabled = true;
   var countdownTimer1 = setInterval('secondPassed1()', 1000);
}
 var seconds1 = 180;
      function secondPassed1() {
          var minutes1 = Math.round((seconds1 - 30)/60),
              remainingSeconds1 = seconds1 % 60;

          if (remainingSeconds1 < 10) {
              remainingSeconds1 = "0" + remainingSeconds1;
          }

          document.getElementById('countdown2').innerHTML = minutes1 + ":" + remainingSeconds1;
          if (seconds1 == 0) {
              clearInterval(countdownTimer1);
             //form1 is your form name
            window.alert("Times Up");
          } else {
              seconds1--;
          }
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: It's working for me in Firefox. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: google chrome .

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Chrome to test in, but it is working in Chromium as well.

Comment: not working in firefox.

Comment: works on chrome 55.0.2883.87

Comment: @Dani is this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f6vc2sk/) working for you?

Comment: What you sent is working but in my code its not.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work as expected (with neither of the timers) because you try to unset an Interval which can not be found which gives an error like *Uncaught ReferenceError: countdownTimer1 is not defined* (Chrome)

You have to change the lines

```
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

and

```
var countdownTimer1 = setInterval('secondPassed1()', 1000);
```

to

```
countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

and

```
countdownTimer1 = setInterval('secondPassed1()', 1000);
```

This makes the variable *countdownTimer* and *countdownTimer1* available in the global scope of your script and then it does work.

Comment: Still same, first button is not working and second one is working

Comment: What do you mean with "not working". Can you click the buttons? Does nothing happen? or does it start the countdown but not showing the alert? Do you see any output in the Script console (Press F12 on windows)

Comment: I mean that when I click on the first timer button it don't do anything but when I click or the second timer button the count down starts and the button gets disabled

Comment: function showDiv() is not working and function showDiv2() is working although they are almost same

Comment: I tried exactly your code with firefox and chrome. Both work so I assume, it  is something local. Does the console output anything?